# Rails - How to pass data from view or url to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails I'm using code from Railscasts #213 revised to build a calendar.  I'm using it to display `Event` hours for each day.

The helper code sets the `background-color` for today, so you can easily see which day is today.

I have it working so that you can click on a day and a table will show detail records of `Events` for that day.

This is the code that is executed when the user clicks on a day in the calendar:

```
<div><%= link_to 'View' , events_index7_path(:date_selected => date), :class => 'btn  btn-mini'%></div>
```

That puts the selected day into the url, like this:

```
 .../events/index7?date_selected=2013-11-22
```

And the view tests for the day_selected like this:

```
<% current_user.events.where(:event_date => @date_selected).each do |event| %>
```

I would like to set the css background-color for the `date_selected`

I'm trying to add the `dayselect` class to the helper:

```
def day_classes(day)
  classes = []
  classes << "today" if day == Date.today
  classes << "dayselect" if day == @date_selected
  classes << "notmonth" if day.month != date.month
  classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
end
```

But, it doesn't recognize `@date_selected`

I also tried this:

```
classes << "dayselect" if day == params[:date_selected]
```

UPDATE1:

This is a pic of the calendar so you better understand what I'm doing:

[image]

UPDATE2

View code for the calendar:

```
  <%= calendar @date do |date| %>
  <%= date.day %>
  <% hours = current_user.events.where(:event_date => date).sum(:hours) %>
  <% if hours != 0 %>
    <div class="sumhours"><%= hours %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div> - </div>
  <% end %>
  <div><%= link_to 'View' , events_index7_path(:date_selected => date), :class => 'btn  btn-mini'%></div>
```

UPDATE3
If I stop execution at the helper code to set the class, I find this:

```
Request parameters  
{"date_selected"=>"2013-11-21", "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"index7"}
```

How do I access the date_selected parameter?

UPDATE4

This will highlight a specific date converted from a string:

```
classes << "dayselect" if day == DateTime.strptime("2013-11-18", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

But, if I used this:

```
  classes << "dayselect" if day == DateTime.strptime(params[:date_selected], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<CalendarHelper
```

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you are using this `day_classes` helper method in your view?

Comment: The helper is from the Railscast episode #213.  The `def day_classes` is just a small part of the helper. The view uses the helper to build a calendar.  I'll add a pic.

Comment: Aside from a pic - can you add the view code that uses this helper?  Also, please show how you are assigning a value to `@date_selected` (I suspect this is a string-date comparison issue)

Comment: `day_classes` isn't being called in this code - can you find and post where it _is_ being called?  Also how @date_selected is being assigned, as I mention above.

Comment: #PinnyM I need to know how to access the request parameter =  date_selected.  See my update 3. Thanks

Comment: `params[:date_selected]` will get you the value - but that value is a string, and you'll need to parse it to a date to properly compare it in the way that `day_classes` method is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do it with Rails, so I used jQuery.

Used pure.js to get the url.

Here's the jQuery (Coffeescript):

```
url = $.url().param("date_selected")

$("#monthcalendar td").each ->
  $(this).addClass "dayselect" if $(this).attr('class') == url
```